# How to define an extra parameter in a ClickHandler?

Tags: c#, parsing

My ClickHandler looks like this:

```
private void TestClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, string test)
    {
         //using "test" in here
    }
```

Now I want to call this function with my extra parameter: `test`. I tried like this but it didnt work:

```
something = new EventHandler(MenuExtraEigenschappenClickHandler(,,"test"));
```

This the error: `argument missing`. Is there another way to parse a string into a ClickHandler? Or is the way correct and should I use the parsing a bit different?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Although an answer exists for this, I would like to point out that I think an alternative more inline with the intended use of tis handlers would be to use the EventArgs parameter and pass a class that derives from it and contains the additional information. You can then cast it back to the type you expect.

Comment: @Juan Thank you for this clear answer!